# Show that a borelien outer measure on a metric space is a metric outer mesure.

Tags: measure-theory

Let $(X,d)$ a metric space and $\mu$ an outer measure on $(X,d)$ s.t. every borel set are $\mu-$Caratheodory measurable. Show that $\mu$ is a meatric outer measure on $(X,d)$.

It mean that I have to prove that $\mu^*(A\cup B)=\mu^*(A)+\mu^*(B)$ if $d(A,B)=\inf\{d(x,y)\mid x\in A,y\in B\}>0$, but I don't have any idea on how prove it.

The fact that $\mu^*(A\cup B)\leq \mu^*(A)+\mu^*(B)$ is obvious. But since I don't have a precise definition of $\mu^*$ (like $\mu^*(E)=\inf\{...\}$) I don't know how to proceed... Any help would be appreciated.